# How to create a shadow effect from layer list programmatically?

Tags: android

I have learned how to create a shadow effect to a textview/button using a layer list. I used this code for reference :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- background color -->
<item
    android:bottom="3px"
    android:left="3px"
    android:right="3px"
    android:top="3px">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#cc2b2b" />


        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- over left shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="180"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerX="0.9"
            android:endColor="#99000000"
            android:startColor="#00FF0000" />

        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- over right shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="360"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerX="0.9"
            android:endColor="#99000000"
            android:startColor="#00FF0000" />

        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- over top shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="-90"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerY="0.9"
            android:endColor="#00FF0000"
            android:startColor="#99000000"
            android:type="linear" />

        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- over bottom shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
            android:centerY="0.9"
            android:endColor="#00FF0000"
            android:startColor="#99000000"
            android:type="linear" />

        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image]

I was wondering how to achieve this dynamically using Layer Drawable/ Gradient Drawable ?
Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

It's gonna be a painful slow process, but certainly totally possible, and it's just following exactly what the XML do:

```
// create the layers
Drawable[] layer = new Drawable[5] // or whatever amount in the XML

// build the layers
layer[0] = new ShapeDrawable();
layer[0]. // call methods here to configure the 1st layer

layer[1] = new ShapeDrawable();
layer[1]. // call methods here to configure the 2nd layer
... etc ...

LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layer);
```

references [LayerDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html), [ShapeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html) and [Drawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html)